# How do I identify this strange white space at the top of my page?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, spacing

I want there to be a distance of 60px between the top of the page and my header where the logo sits. However, there seems to be 16px of white space there already. Because of this I have just added a margin-top of 44px to the header, achieving what I wanted.

But I would much rather identify where the 16px of white space is coming from, not only to learn from it but also to make it neater: if I could just expand the white space instead of adding any margin, that would be ideal.

I don't think the mystery space is margin nor padding... I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a:

```
<br style="clear:both;"></br>
```

Inside your 'wrapper' div, just below the 'content' div.
It's basically a new line, it's 16px tall because of the 16px font size which is the default.

Use your browser's page inspector for things like that.
It is a handy tool for examining your page's structure and looks.

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML file **Line 68** change the body tag style to this :

```
body {
    line-height: 0;
    background: url("http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/modernist/style/../images/back_01.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "RobotoRegular", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #606060;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `div.wrapper`, right before your `div.header` you have a `br`. That is your 16px !

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <br style="clear:both;">   <!-- mysterious 16px -->
    <div class="header">
```